# Cannot bind ItemsSource to ElementName

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

This is probably a silly question, but I can't make a simple example with ItemsSource work. My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestDataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDataGrid"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Height="250" Width="300" Name="MyWindow">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, ElementName=MyWindow}" Background="{Binding MyBrush, ElementName=MyWindow}"/>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Item> items;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        items.Add(new Item { Key = "Key1", Value = "Value1" });
        items.Add(new Item { Key = "Key2", Value = "Value2" });
        items.Add(new Item { Key = "Key3", Value = "Value3" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> MyItems
    {
        get { return items; }
    }

    public Brush MyBrush
    {
        get { return Brushes.LightPink; }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

It works if I set ItemsSource in code, or if I set `DataContext=this` and then remove ElementName from my binding. But why doesn't it work with ElementName?
I can bind the background color like this, but not collection.

I know how to make it work with DataContext, or in code-behind, but I'm interested in why this particular example doesn't work, am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know how to make it work with DataContext, or in code-behind, but I'm interested in why this particular example doesn't work, am I missing something?

As pointed out by @Clemens your binding will actually work if you populate the source collection *before* the InitializeComponent() is called.

The difference between setting a DataContext in code behind and creating an ElementName Binding in XAML is that the latter is already established during the `InitializeComponent` call. Items that are added later - to a collection that does not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` - are ignored.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    items.Add(new Item { Key = "Key1", Value = "Value1" });
    items.Add(new Item { Key = "Key2", Value = "Value2" });
    items.Add(new Item { Key = "Key3", Value = "Value3" });
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

You could also bind to the parent window using a RelativeSource though, This works:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: "Because "MyItems" is not a property of the base type Window with which the root element is declared in your XAML markup." This explanation is wrong. The actual problem is just timing. If you fill the `items` collection before calling `InitializeComponent`, the ElementName Binding works well.

Comment: I don't think it works he is binding `MyItems`, not `items` and he didn't do a setter in `MyItems` to link it to `items`

Comment: Even with a RelativeSource Binding it works only by chance. Better always use an ObservableCollection.

Comment: @Safe Didn't you notice the `MyItems` getter in the question?

Comment: @Clemens ah yes my bad I was on the first version of this answer xD

Comment: Isn't the problem that at the time InitializeComponent() is called, the collection was not created and set to null? If I create collection before InitializeComponent() and fill items afterwards, then it works too.

Answer (score 1):

You set your `MyItems` after initializing your windows and since `MyItems` in your example doesn't implement a setter and the `INotifyPropertyChanged` manner, your UI thread is never warn by the change you made on your collection.

Here two solutions you can set up:

**SOLUTION 1**

Instantiate your Observable collection directly in the get:

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> MyItems {
        get {
            var _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            _items.Add(new Item { Key = "Key1", Value = "Value1" });
            _items.Add(new Item { Key = "Key2", Value = "Value2" });
            _items.Add(new Item { Key = "Key3", Value = "Value3" });
            return _items;
        }
    }
```

**SOLUTION 2**

Use `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

Like that when you set your items, Your UI thread knows there is a change to do in the xaml part

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> MyItems {
        get { return _items; }
        set {
            _items = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyItems)));
        }
    }

    public MainWindow () {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        MyItems.Add(new Item { Key = "Key1", Value = "Value1" });
        MyItems.Add(new Item { Key = "Key2", Value = "Value2" });
        MyItems.Add(new Item { Key = "Key3", Value = "Value3" });
    }

....
```

Comment: Your first "solution" gives a really bad advice. You should by no means do it that way.

Comment: Yes I don't like the second solution too in a way, I was just giving simple examples, the first solution should be more like @mm8 answer.

Comment: No, it does something very different. It creates a new collection each time the property getter is called. You should avoid that.