# If setting a DataContext within a constructor, does it matter if I set it before or after the call to InitializeComponent()?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF window that takes a few parameters in it's constructor.  I then use these constructors to setup the state of the window.  Part of that constructor process is instantiating my view model class that is then set as the windows `DataContext`.

My question is when should I set my `DataContext` equal to my view model object-- before or after the call to `InitializeComponent()`?

I ask because if I set it beforehand, I then need to manually launch code that is executed *after* the window has been initialized, because certain events should fire when the `DataContext` is assigned, or re-assigned.

It is my assumption that there shouldn't be any binding issues if I set the `DataContext` after the call to `InitializeComponent()` but I wanted to ask for advice on the matter before making the final call to wire up my window this way.  Could I be missing something the could come back to haunt me if I set my `DataContext` after the call to `InitializeComponent()`?

Comment: You answered your question, setting `DataContext` prior calling `InitializeComponents()` (which task is to load/parse/process xaml) will require refreshing (e.g. setting it to `null` and then back), so it has to be set after.

Comment: I always set DataContext after InitializeComponent, never had any problems that were strictly related to that fact.

Comment: My advice is to handle it differently: Do not set the window datacontext from within the window. Instead, set the datacontext on a child element within the window (eg. Grid) and do it in the Window.Loaded event, not in constructor. However, if I remember correctly this is more relevant to UserControl than to Window, and I just adapted the approach generally as a habit.

Comment: @grek40 I understand what you are explaining, but please expound why that's the (likely) right approach.  In fact, briefly address my question but explain your suggestion in an answer.  If I see the merits, I'll give you the answer mark.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I can write an answer later, not enough time now and need to re-check a few nitty details for the answer to be of any worth.

Comment: @grek40 Ok, thanks.  I'm not sure if this question will get much attention anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is when should I set my DataContext equal to my view model object-- before or after the call to InitializeComponent()?

It shouldn't matter unless you rely on some bindings that are established during the call to the InitializeComponent(), like `ElementName` bindings:

[Cannot bind ItemsSource to ElementName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006829/cannot-bind-itemssource-to-elementname/42007019#42007019)

The `InitializeComponent()` method itself locates a URI to the compiled XAML file and passes it to a `LoadComponent()` method that parses the BAML, i.e. the compiled XAML, and creates instances of the elements that you have defined in your XAML markup:

[What is the connection between .xaml and .xaml.cs files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41344321/what-is-the-connection-between-xaml-and-xaml-cs-files/41345998#41345998)

Simply setting the `DataContext` property of the window to an instance of a view model class that elements in the view bind to might as well be done after the call to the `InitializeComponent()` method. These bindings aren't resolved before the constructor returns anyway.

Comment: I've just made test where I set `DataContext` before `InitializeComponents`, and my Bindings were resolved before `InitializeComponents` returned

Answer (score 4):

Here's my addition to @mm8's answer:

1. Usually it does not matter, but set DataContext after InitializeComponents. When `DataContextChanged` event is called, you naturally expect, that components are already initialized.

   Also it's good to know whether the components can be initialized without DataContext and separate possible initialization issues from binding issues. If you set DataContext before InitializeComponents, the binding issues may result in an exception in InitializeComponents.
2. Make you ViewModel constructor very fast. Don't do any DB calls or any I/O calls, etc. You want to display the UI as soon as possible.
3. Make sure your ViewModel constructor never throws an exception. Parameter validations is OK, but just for debugging purposes. It should never happen in production.
4. If you need to load data into viewmodel, create separate async method called e.g. `Activate()`, which you will call from View's `Loaded` or `OnNavigatedTo` event.

   Additionally, if you subscribe to some events in ViewModel, you should unsubscribe. Ideal place for subscription is Activate method, resp `Deactivate` to unsubscribe. If you subscribe in ViewModel's ctor, it may happen that Activate/Deactivate will never be called and you introduced memory leak.
5. If you feel your bindings are slowing the UI, try to use `{Binding IsAsync=True}`, resp `x:Bind`, or try to use codebehind to set the properties in worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Different from what you ask, I suggest two changes:

1. Set the `DataContext` of an inner element and not on the `Window` / `UserControl` itself.
2. Set the `DataContext` on `Loaded` instead of the constructor.

These points are more obvious when looking at a `UserControl`, which will probably be embedded at multiple points, but remember that a `Window` can be created by explicit startup code instead of some `App.StartupUri`.

Regarding the first point, consider the OOP design basics. Forget about WPF / XAML specifics and remember that you derive from a `Window` class and create a subclass of it. The contract of this class includes a public get/set property named `DataContext` which accepts any kind of `object`. So you should at least think about, how bad you will screw up, if someone is replacing your `DataContext` from the outside. When you instead set the `DataContext` on the next-inner `FrameworkElement` inside the window, it is hosted in an environment that is owned by the window.

Setting the `DataContext` on `Loaded` is working for me, while I ran into problems with constructor time setting. However, I can't actually recall the details of it, maybe it was related to the visual designer (that I'm not using anymore). For other controls it is easier to explain: constructor time initialization sucks when hosted in a virtualizing panel, also property initializers (`new MyControl { Prop = Value }`, XAML property assignments, ...) are not handled by time the constructor runs, so objects tend to be in a different state than how they are presented later.

Comment: If an exception occurs in usercontrols ctor, then you will get something like XamlInitializationExeption, which may be confusing. Other issue you may have experienced is slowing down ui, if the viemodel ctor takes too long. But I dont recommend setting viewmodel in loaded event.

Comment: @Liero most of the time I'm binding the viewmodel from an external source anyway, so I don't have to worry about timing and changes, but in case you want to establish an internal datacontext, where / how would you do that and why is the loaded event not a good place?

Comment: You should not set DataContext in Loaded EventHandler, because at that point, the DataContext is already inherited from the parent. So Imagine you have `WindowViewModel` and `UserControlViewModel`. If you set datacontext in `UserControl.Loaded` event, you are changing it from `WindowViewModel` to `UserControlViewModel`